# How to select * from DataTable Where... using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to filter a datatable with linq, I have tried doing this..

```
string strFind = "Road";
var query = from a in res.AsEnumerable()
             where (a.Field<string>("Last Name") == strFind || 
             a.Field<string>("First Name") == strFind ||
             a.Field<string>("Address") == strFind)                  
             select a;
```

I have about 5 other columns that I got to filter out as well, this is testing code right now to see if it would work, and it doesn't.
I tried putting the datatable to a list and filtering by using .Contains(strFind) but that didn't work out for me either.

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not enough.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Fair enough. Its not returning anything.

Comment: @MitchWheat, nope. I double checked that earlier and made sure that what I was searching for is actually in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LINQ query doesn't actually do anything to the list you're querying.  That query gives you a list of results.  If you want the user to see those results then you have to actually show them those results, e.g. call `ToArray` or `ToList` or, in this case, `CopyToDataTable` and then bind that result to a grid or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It also works :

```
   var query = res.AsEnumerable()
         where (a.Field<string>("Last Name") .CustomContains(strFind,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
         a.Field<string>("First Name") .CustomContains(strFind,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
         a.Field<string>("Address") .CustomContains(strFind,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
         ).ToList()
```

Use the below Extension Method to solve the Case sensitivity in *strFind*

```
 public static bool CustomContains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison compare)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(toCheck, compare) >= 0;

    }
```